# excel formula to combine 2 cells into 1 in specific format

Tags: excel

I have 2 cells, one cell has just text A1 cell, text (hello) other cell B1 has a timestamp (3:55). I need to combine these cell to one with this format: hello#t=3m55s, or if timastamp is 1:12:11 format will be hello#t=1h12m11s. So cell A1 will change to this specific format base on B1 cell.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this formula:

```
=A1&"#t="&IF(HOUR(B1)=0,"",HOUR(B1)&"h")&MINUTE(B1)&"m"&SECOND(B1)&"s"
```

The `&` concatenates each part together. However, if the timestamps are not correct for the `mm:ss` times, then it won't work.

EDIT: To deal with the issue of timestamps:

`=A1&"#t="&IF(SECOND(B1)<>0,HOUR(B1)&"h"&MINUTE(B1)&"m"&SECOND(B1)&"s", HOUR(B1)&"m"&MINUTE(B1)&"s")`

The issue with this is that it won't work for timestamps of the type "11:11:**00**" But I don't think there's much to be done, unless the string is first converted to text, which I could give some pointers on.

Comment: Jerry, thank you for your quick respond and your formula. It work perfectly when I enter 1:11:11 but when I enter 5:55 (5minutes 55second) it will display 5h55m0s.

Comment: @Vlad yes, that's why I included "However, if the timestamps are not correct for the mm:ss times, then it won't work", because `3:55` is actually being considered as `h:mm` by excel. I'm trying to find a workaround.

Comment: @Vlad could you try the other formula I put in my answer?

Comment: oh ok, I formatted the cell by text so cell is treated as text even when a number is in the cell. However it didn't help.

Comment: I see only one formula =A1&"#t="&IF(HOUR(B1)=0,"",HOUR(B1)&"h")&MINUTE(B1)&"m"&SECOND(B1)&"s"

Comment: @Vlad Try to refresh the page. There's usually a little bar called "An edit has been made to this answer" or similar.